# Flask incomplete response received from application

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning flask and i've built my first application - to go further with it I decided to host it.

While the application works perfect on my PC - it breaks on the server but only with some specific paremeters passed (it works for most of the form inputs):

E.g
for most posted values the application returns proper dataframe, but for some (I tried like 50 and 2 break the code returning Incomplete response received from application)

Here are the two related app.routes:

```
@app.route("/searchcharacter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def charactersearch():
    if request.method == "POST":
        character_name = request.form["nm"]
        character_name = character_name.replace("%20", " ")
        print(character_name) 
        return redirect(url_for("character_found", character=character_name))
    else:    
        return render_template("searchcharacter.html")


@app.route("/<character>/")
def character_found(character):
    character = character.replace("%20", " ")
    print("Character right before query: " + character)
    df_character = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM auction_history where character_name = %(character)s"""
                               , con=db_connection,params={'character': character})     
    df = df_character[['character_name','auction_start','auction_end','win_lose','minimum_bid','winning_bid','level','vocation',
                       'sex','server','axe_fighting','sword_fighting','club_fighting','dist_fighting','fishing', 'magic_level','shielding']]
    df.columns = ['Name', 'Auction Start', 'Auction End', 'Auction Successful?', 'Min Bid', 'Winning Bid', 'Level', 'Vocation', 'Sex', 
                  'Server', 'Axe', 'Sword', 'Club', 'Distance', 'Fishing', 'Magic Level', 'Shielding']
    
    df['Auction Successful?'] = df['Auction Successful?'].replace([1],'Yes')
    df['Auction Successful?'] = df['Auction Successful?'].replace([0],'No')
    print(df_character)
    if df_character.empty:
        return render_template("characternotfound.html", character=character)
    else:
        return render_template("characterfound.html", character=character,   tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)
```

I've looked at everything that could come to my mind... but I am buffled why it works for some input and doesn't work for other.
The examples of inputs that don't work:
Chamstwa nie zniese,
Bourk the sioless

Examples that work:
Mac Nekro,
Japatrocinador Da Roleta,
Tirinha Malfada

If that helps the webiste is already hosted and running at: http://tanalyst.pl/searchcharacter

I would really appreciate any help... this just breaks my head :)
I tried to look through the logs and it looks to me that for the not working inputs flask doesn't redirect properly?

What else can I look at? It looks like get requests for the not working ones give 502 html response

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Coud it be one of the two templates that is broken? characternotfound.html or characterfound.html

Comment: maybe you should use [urllib.parse.unquote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) to not just decode spaces

Comment: Thanks for your time man - i looked through the templates and disabled some aspects to test, they look fine...
I also tried urlib.parse.unquote and it didnt help - i am hard stuck on this

Comment: Do you have a test string that you know you can find in the database? Try to minimize the code and data in database still producing the error and you may find the answer. It's difficult to help but I can see " n" triggers the error but not " o" works but not found. Empty string gives a not found error. And after the error the server freezes for about 10 seconds suggesting the error is some kind of infinite loop running in background

Comment: I am starting to notice some trends with the strings that cause issues:
the sioless,
nie siedze, nie znies

if only i remove space before the second word it works fine. Bourk the Sioless is definitely in the database and if i run the app on my windows pc it works with no issues

Comment: Do you see both debug print() in the log?

Comment: print("Character right before query: " + character) - this one never prints the strings which break the script (prints the working ones just fine). So I guess that means the app breaks on redirect? Can I somehow pass the string without having it in url?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you return arbitrary string before reaching your template rendering? Try find out which row is causing the error by adding for example `return "reached this line"`

Comment: You can do an initial search in the `charactersearch()` function and then just pass a row identifier to the next page. Or save the search string in a different table in the database. and pass the identifier in that table

Comment: Or use the same url for both functions but set `methods=["GET"]` on the first one and `methods=["POST"]` on the one handling the search

Comment: i added render template instead of redirect to 'POST" method and I think it works... so the issue is redirect?

Comment: and thanks man at least it gives proper results now! gotta figure out how to adjust it now. really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It may be some weird rewrite rule in the server because urls not related to this is matched and gives the same error. For example http://tanalyst.pl/a/%20n/a/

Actually any path containing either "[a-z]%[any two digits]s" or "%[any two digits]n" or "%[any two digits][h or j or l or q or s or t or z]n  is failing.

Maybe an other `@app.route("url-selector")` functions in flask that interferes

`/<character>/` may be too general and catch all. Maybe you should change it to `/results/<character>`

Comment: I only have following as routes:
@app.route("/contact")
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/searchcharacter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@app.route("/<character>")

Do you know where i can read about server rewrite rules? I see that the linky you posted y doesnt exist but virtually breaks my application (lags it heavily)

Comment: `@app.route("/<character>/")` is very general and catch all urls

Comment: i changed the app route earlier while testing everything that came to my mind to @app.route("/results/<character>") and also to @app.route("/searchresults/<character>") with no success

but I think i will have to remove this route at all since it will be useless now. I am a little worried about the /a/%20n/a lagging the app tho - will research that
I owe you a beer man, really appreciate your time

Comment: Server and rewrite preferences depends on which programs you use to serve your app. How did you set it up?

Comment: i think it's phusion passenger - this is what the hosting service mentions. All I really had to do was set up one additional python script that imports my app

Comment: Don't know about phusion passenger. Found that any path containing either "[any charachter]%20s" or "%20n" is failing.